# How w3.eth.filter('latest').get_new_entries() works exactly?

Tags: web3.py, python

I try to monitor new transactions.

```
from web3.auto import w3
import time

l = w3.eth.filter('latest')

while True:
  ts = time.time()
  ll = l.get_new_entries()
  for i in ll:
      print('===== Block hash:  ', i.hex())
      block_hash = i.hex()
      block = w3.eth.getBlock(block_hash, full_transactions=True)
      transactions = block['transactions']
      print('===== Block Number: ', block['number'])
      for tx in transactions:
         print(ts, '   From wallet: ', tx['from'])
         print(ts, '   Value ETH: ', tx['value'])
```

The result for Ropsten test network was:

```
===== Block hash:   0x0297b09d64f5db2df68cf8dca56323bd6c021306fb9227e1a668b79155819bee
===== Block Number:  2081162
1548529910.8412573    From wallet:  0xFF8705243e84B8DAD8b0A25B7c76CFa48456e4D5
1548529910.8412573    Value ETH:  100000000000000000
1548529910.8412573    From wallet:  0x8eD3077e18D536d38d31c379e4f407540275876E
1548529910.8412573    Value ETH:  200000000000000000
1548529910.8412573    From wallet:  0xeDc3fbcf9F7F0E9dFD2Fc31bD8ad9BA1DD632322
1548529910.8412573    Value ETH:  0
1548529910.8412573    From wallet:  0xeDc3fbcf9F7F0E9dFD2Fc31bD8ad9BA1DD632322
1548529910.8412573    Value ETH:  0
1548529910.8412573    From wallet:  0xE49aEAaC12e3323d675669A3Da2ED018a7929a0B
1548529910.8412573    Value ETH:  0
===== Block hash:   0x2102996c79e7a599eb3ca0b9d13276c135193413128d95266d1b8ad503cd5cfe
===== Block Number:  2081163
1548529910.9399285    From wallet:  0x77F71e7C2Be802cc7f531d177647E07163c9c756
1548529910.9399285    Value ETH:  0
```

If latest block

> 2081163

then my first loop

> While True:

gives me several transactions

> 1548529910.9399285    From wallet:  0x77F71e7C2Be802cc7f531d177647E07163c9c756
>   1548529910.9399285    Value ETH:  0

if this block is not closed by miners, then my second loop while True gives me next transactions from this block?

Or

```
l = w3.eth.filter('latest')
ll = l.get_new_entries()
```

works only after latest block closed by miners?